# jQuery Mobile Pop Up from Table <td>

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

can you please let me know how I can enable to jquery Mobile Pop up from clicking inside a Table `<td>` element?

what I have so far is

```
<td class="tdgameday" id="12"><a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">Info</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
  </div>
</td>
```

bust user MUST click exactly on the Info link, is there any way to enable  to do this? thanks

Comment: Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/Ad22d/90/ click add expense button

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `div` over the text filling the whole `td` element.

```
<td class="tdgameday" id="12">
 <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">
   <div style="height:100%; width:100%">Info</div>
 </a>
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
   <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
 </div>
</td>
```